# Convenience initializer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create some sort of `initWithDictionary` initializer for one of my model in Swift. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class CityModel: NSObject {

    var country: String
    var mapLat: String
    var mapLng: String
    var mapZoom: Int
    var name: String
    var nameShort: String
    var timezone: String
    var token: String

    init(country: String, mapLat: String, mapLng: String, mapZoom: Int, name: String, nameShort: String, timezone: String, token: String) {
        self.country = country
        self.mapLat = mapLat
        self.mapLng = mapLng
        self.mapZoom = mapZoom
        self.name = name
        self.nameShort = nameShort
        self.timezone = timezone
        self.token = token
    }

    convenience init(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self.init(
            country: (dict["country"] as String),
            mapLat: (dict["mapLat"] as String), // error
            mapLng: (dict["mapLng"] as String),
            mapZoom: (dict["mapZoom"] as Int),
            name: (dict["name"] as String),
            nameShort: (dict["nameShort"] as String),
            timezone: (dict["timezone"] as String),
            token: (dict["token"] as String)
        )
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
CityModel.swift:34:18: Extra argument 'mapLat' in call
```

And I'm afraid I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `dict` declaration to:

```
dict: Dictionary<String, Any>
```

It's because you're using a mix of types including non-class types.

More information in Swift docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_505

That "Extra argument" error message is a red-herring. I've found that it's usually complaining about the type of an argument not matching.